# How to use limit and order_by together in Django rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-orm

I want to use limit on following as [1:10]

```
data = GroupPostsModel.objects.filter(
        group_id=group_id) & GroupPostsModel.objects.filter(post_type=post_type).order_by('-time_stamp')
```

I try this

```
data = GroupPostsModel.objects.filter(
        group_id=group_id & GroupPostsModel.objects.filter(post_type=post_type)[1:10].order_by('-time_stamp')
```

But did not work..!

Comment: Have you tried `GroupPostsModel.objects.filter(
        group_id=group_id & GroupPostsModel.objects.filter(post_type=post_type).order_by('-time_stamp')[1:10]` the slice should be at the last.

Comment: Hi @Ahtisham, Django does not allow using ```&``` or ```|``` without [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) objects. also you can't just write another query in filter just like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order first, then slice. Like so:

```py
data = GroupPostsModel.objects.filter(group_id=group_id, post_type=post_type).order_by('-time_stamp')[1:10]
```

> ***Note:** It's advised to wrap slices on QuerySets in `try` `except` functions. As if the slice fails then it will raise an exception*

Comment: Thanks, it works...! Thanks for the Note :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the query given above works,

```
data = GroupPostsModel.objects.filter(
        group_id=group_id) & GroupPostsModel.objects.filter(post_type=post_type).order_by('-time_stamp')

data=  data[1:10]
```

Or You can just follow this syntax

```
data = ClassName.objects.filter(your conditions)[1:10]
```

Comment: It also works thanks Aakash...! :)